# Postman parsing data into excel

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, postman

The code I wrote is having a single error(that I know of). That error being:
line 44, in 
Match_Address1= store["addressLine1"]
KeyError: 'addressLine1'

The goal of the code is to scrape Mcdonalds website and grab location information and phone number to put into excel. This is so I can track closures and location changes to a previous list.I used postman to help set up a payload, etc to get the information.I know that I am getting all the information back(address,phone and more) from the link but parsing it somehow is being trickier than I thought. If anyone can point me in the right direction that be great!

My guess is that I am not going into 'features' properly to the subsection  called properties where the information I want is located. However that is just my guess.

Also, if it helps I can post the original code that just prints all the information.

Thanks in advance

```
import requests
import csv
import json

url = "https://www.mcdonalds.com/googleapps/GoogleRestaurantLocAction.do?method=searchLocation&latitude=43.6936965&longitude=-79.2969938&radius=1000000&maxResults=1700&country=ca&language=en-ca&showClosed=&hours24Text=Open%2024%20hr"

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.mcdonalds.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/restaurant-locator.html',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'cookie': 'bm_sz=C04645E7F7A956C5F9D9C5A20DEAEC97~YAAQ1Cv2SEtfMBN6AQAAItxfEwwTVV2V2Tr7UWpPt1Ps7gl84FzQlmbWIm4kBBh5dxlK3w8RenwiEiKtvERE6dLmrwPwJUuy+14gU/LeEZvP+uxzyBr04oQXdcSEQuiOgdkAGasqnBrTw1mp5E5iehnRpvHBDdSqh8wRSgJV0eG4f8YwSz66BfntCBALtQNCAFK2; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~0~YAAQ1Cv2SExfMBN6AQAAItxfEwaIwCrBeP25JBhBb7TX+HmnLQgrj1TkosrB+oHSv9ctrxRukqEDUaHPL1KkjpqjY1XY1yyulQ0ZRhsEfhY968YVsTOqfiosAu3kykd3pJG/bQ37XHwWs5qXpIdhMXRwJwXmkYtl3ETG8kXK2iZ22Q31COaSjNVACLaa7s9tCk9ItgLvUj5x9Nldjnd8AdXR0pXicrQY1IaruJyNqwMcJv42AUHW7iH4Ex9ZOSYsgEjLMNd44mS525X/gSNUTSOzoqoWsnH4MU59vfgLTwc2hVncAv67LBViTLxbWw4eVAvz7Z5phQfCmvoIy0PD8gy5iwPDMaD3GASrK9xScDPAPUI2wquxmSJ+f2cQaxZQKhvJCeH9cz14OZfx8ksA2ss53E0l0kDvgmnw~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=BA4817D8DEE20E92C1E6251C54FC124348F62BD48F5F00005F91C9608B679D5F~plUkbYfsvYr5dCayJ9dMGEJ3QDgkmkv2mLpE7pCY9vW0xrdawvmyxfSnupw/4F7C48Akdn8PKsBniqz+7F+RZb8v4AkvH3c0RuvnynqJoni+kJcDYtPOxdMvdtGdTlZGIkSQNfpcxHNQDVlzojdSBX0vyBh/8seKQv10U67M7m787olYzg9jnsUwk3/VHBrnMDogiWJT8rNV7saSXunN0pAgucZWo/XhCpTJL+tI9urt0=; MCDCountry_code=US; bm_mi=BEE06312635FD442995BC0237BAFDA7C~f/RxgMW/JJSUc/wB9ZRg9fPD/76+wq/TaoWEZR1/ttrAiVTO256xhDTsVYc/kdHIjWkxvfO4XDcBjqe4hQ4qXt8Anpfi09vna/zcC7l6OVWpWeRSoZNztl7h5VF407L3XG+9CpzjSHNcaqAPRk5d0J5gLMtL/KmR8XBkAC0Syim7ST97nxNrPfLdlkSPMGm4Oy86xvY5PH5Nu47zS/gwhanBFg69tAdrQdaZewE2eGuzoJPsZit3UsihTzhXc4LY92hfSdh3/kZRId+NE8Jp0w==; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN4a9yst3R170rBCm1egzGvCBmB1jq9aCwQm5VgIJgloPOdpiIPfD3kDxFbKhqMuS5U=; JSESSIONID=64PZkBXhhpvNjM4NganzSZ0r1npIIaM7Fo84EsxN.eap7node7; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~-1~YAAQ1Cv2SExyMBN6AQAA5Et0EwZueCejZbKz1VDGCq2sB43Yx4dq0SiiGeUS6gVpXRIdw3rA3OdpNGHq7tVzQ+IvPpEKwLML9736x1qB5SQxV3jai89y2B2QF6K8nKtyrDAes0qbeTyIrHu0Rh1HLs7CjNxiLi0wswbCZfSsPI6fJZiEt+Itre3lfmua/HkhIRwpVTKqlVN5eQ8XIX+s1jJbINx/jUmMTW+jB5k4A5NARGChYH7rJQGYIT/oyZYpSbS3Yweqa4FRgGMW4gYZBN39+t2xSfewADLdpihfOnoZtakw9VhcvAKaf4mEzjB7WEfNJIZSjSE8DzvbJNIF41MGuAhhrnEBwBE8uVCZsA+2qjVPSADVp2Nn8JanJXCbucnLFOLsmPz3oVtGzentht1cHog4+eYOUlmw~0~-1~-1; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN5ZCTzA250oKEeVeXaa6j4gEGJ9RRtrTXQdYXzzSx6fM9aLwif+We2vtIc1yLQgTt4=',
  'dnt': '1'
} 

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files)


stores = json.loads(response.text)

with open('Mcdonlocation.csv', mode='w') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow([
        "addressLine1",
        "addressLine2",
        "addressLine3",
        "subDivision",
        "postcode",
        "telephone"
        ])

    for store in stores['features']:
        row = []
        Match_Address1= store["addressLine1"]
        Match_Address2= store["addressLine2"]
        Match_Address3= store["addressLine3"]
        subDivision= store["subDivision"]
        Postalcode= store["postcode"]
        Phone= store["telephone"]

        row.append(Match_Address1)
        row.append(Match_Address2)
        row.append(Match_Address3)
        row.append(subDivision)
        row.append(Postalcode)
        row.append(Phone)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: typo Match_Adress1 should be Match_Address1

Comment: Oh lol thanks, I fixed that but I still get  error: Match_Address1= store["addressLine1"]
KeyError: 'addressLine1' . Any clue whats that is about ?

Comment: sorry, no, maybe list keys of store and see if it is what you expect?